# running setTimeout multiple times for ajax call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, settimeout

I have a webpage where a user can post a question, the question is posted and on success response appends text to a div 'your question was posted.'  Then the div fades away after 1 second.

If the user posts a second question (without refreshing the page), the question is successfully inserted to the database, but the text is not appending to the div.

Do I need to clear the timeout each time the users posts?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#postquestion').on('submit',function(e) {
        $.ajax({
            url:'/question.php',
            data:$(this).serialize(),
            type:'POST',
            success:function(data){         
                if($.trim(data) == "success") {
                    $('<div align=\"center\" style=\"padding-top:10px\"><p style=\"font-weight:bold;font-size:14px\">Your question has been posted.</p></div>').appendTo('#product_question');
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $('#product_question').fadeOut('fast');
                    }, 1000);
                }
            },  
            error:function(data){
                $("#error").show().fadeOut(5000);   
            }
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: and then what happens after you refresh the page? Does the 2nd question show up?

Comment: yeh it shows after refreshing the page

Comment: but the text that should display 'your question was posted' doesnt show the second time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you're calling fadeOut on the div you are appending the the message to, so when it comes back round that div is still hidden when it appends the text

also removing the div from the dom after the fadeOut will make sure that there is only ever one of those divs in the dom at one time

```
$('<div id=\"test\" align=\"center\" style=\"padding-top:10px\"><p style=\"font-weight:bold;font-size:14px\">Your question has been posted.</p></div>').appendTo('#product_question');
setTimeout(function() {
    $('#test').fadeOut('fast').remove();
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Yes this it what I think is happening, how to fix this?

Comment: the code I pasted should work, maybe change the name of the id - but that should fix it

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the problem is that the second time it cant apply because your '#product_question' is hidden. Or maybe you have multiple '#product_question' by the time user posts the second question? Maybe you should try using a class 'product_question' instead of id? '.product_question' vs '#product_question' is your styles.

Answer (score 0):

Mate, I guess you're using way too much code in there. Have a hidden div as:

```
<div id="test" class="myclass" align="center" style="padding-top:10px; display:none;"><p style="font-weight:bold;font-size:14px;">Your question has been posted.</p></div>
```

and then show it on your call back:

```
if($.trim(data) == "success") {

$('.myclass').css('display','block');

setTimeout(function() {
   $('.myclass').fadeOut('fast');
}, 1000);

}
```